# spark parquet conversion issue with malformed lines in file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a "\u0001" delimited file reading with spark for parquet conversion and I don't have any issues with schema, but, data has quotes(") in between without an end quote. I tried different solutions but couldn't figured out any.

```
val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("delimiter", "\u0001")
    //.option("quote", "\"")
    //.option("quote", null)
    //.option("quoteMode", "ALL")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("mode","FAILFAST")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true")
    .option("nullValue"," ")
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
    .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
    .schema(schema)
    .load(fileLocation)
```

Thanks in advance and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","\u0001")`

and read as textFile

```
val sentences = sparkContext.textFile(directoryPath)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually we are dealing with different types and building in a generic framework for more than 1000+ tables, so we started using csv reader